# Perl XMLIn Parser Error - premature end of data problems

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, parse-error

I am very new to Perl and XML, so please be patient with me.

I am having problems with my XMLIn randomly not liking the returned XML file, even though if I open the two different XML return files they are identical.

I came up with this solution:

```
#Send HTTP Request
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();   
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $endpointurl);
$req->content("@XML");

#Get HTTP Response Status
my $resp = $browser->request($req);

#Get Response Status
my $parser = XML::LibXML::Simple->new();
my $xmlResp = ();
$xmlResp = eval { $parser->XMLin($resp->content()) };
unless ($xmlResp)
{
    $xmlResp = eval { $parser->XMLin($resp->content()) };
}
```

But i'm not sure if that's "good practice", or what a better way to have it loop through the return if it fails would be.

This seems to work, but I know that doesn't make it "right".

*** This part of the code was supplied from UPS, I didn't write it, and I don't 100% understand it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: I added the bit of the script that is erroring.  It would be more of a help to just tell me that you want to see the script.  I am very new to Perl and XML, and as you can tell, I have very few posts on here.

Comment: Read **[mcve]**.

Comment: I updated with a bit more of the code.  i -think- it's using XML::LibXML, but it might not be.  The supplied code doesn't have me using the XML::Simple Mod, but i'm very new to all of this, and maybe using XML::LibXML::Simple is just a different way of calling the deprecated scripts?

Comment: @K.Davis  I did not add the solution.  That is just more of the code showing how i'm calling the mod.  This is from UPS' canned dev scripts, I didn't write it, so there may be something in the way they wrote it that's breaking.

Comment: May I put the additional script back in so that someone can maybe help me with the problem?

Comment: This is not a perl problem. You need to examine the error and also probably the content.

Comment: And, as already mentioned, it's pretty useless to attempt to parse the same content multiple times.

Comment: that's the problem.  there's nothing wrong with the file. if I run it again, exact same file, it parses with no problems.  The only thing I can think of is that maybe the UPS servers lag a bit at sending the response, so it tries to process the half finished XML, but since it finishes writing the XML file before I pull it, everything looks fine.  I can't come up with any other reason.  The errors that it's saying are there, are not there when I pull the file.  All the XML tags are closed and ended correctly.

Answer (score 1):

[$resp->content](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Response#$r-%3Econtent) contains an error message if the request was not successful, which is not valid XML. The program should stop if it's a permanent error, retry if it's a transient error, and only parse the content on success.

```
use LWP::UserAgent::Determined qw();
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent::Determined->new;
...
my $resp = $browser->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $parser = ... etc. etc.
} else {
    die sprintf "could not POST to <%s>:\nStatus %s\n%s\n"
        $endpointurl, $resp->status_line, $resp->content;
}
```

Comment: I know what the error is, that's not the problem.  The problem is that it's trying to process the incomplete XML file, which is why when I run the same command again everything works fine.  There must be just enough time that it finishes writing to the file.  That's all I can come up with.

Comment: Alright, I suspect the lack of error checking on the HTTP request; I have edited my answer above.

Comment: ok, so that looks like it will catch the error a little nicer, but will that also take care of the problem of the script trying to read the XML file before it's finished? If I'm understanding it correctly the check for $resp->is_success is checking to see if it's all there, but if it's not, it fails.  Is there a way to have it check, if it fails, wait and check again, if it fails a second time, then die?  It seems like it's a matter a few ms that's causing the problem.

Comment: There is no file, it's an HTTP response. [`is_success` checks the status code only.](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/HTTP-Message-6.14/lib/HTTP/Status.pm#L109) Did you try the code? If yes, do you still get parsing failures? ––– What makes you think the response object changes after the `request` method has finished? Either you're misinterpreting what you're seeing or we don't have the full picture. Please enable us to reproduce the error on our own, the guesswork is tiresome.

Comment: completely understandable!  I'll try your code and see what it does, if it's still erroring, I will let you know and I'll see what I can do to get you all the pieces to try to recreate it.  Thank you for the help!!